# Help with solving this fraction

Tags: fractions, radicals

> Solve for $h$:
>   $$125=\pi \left (\dfrac{5}{\sqrt[3]{\pi}} \right )^2h$$

This is from an optimization problem, in which the volume is the constraint of $125$. I've done everything in the problem except finding this last dimension $h$. The answer is $h=\dfrac{5}{\sqrt[3]{\pi}}$, but I can't seem to get that. Can you show steps please? Thanks.

Comment: Convert all the radicals to exponents and then use exponent laws to simplify everything if that helps. Then divide both sides by the coefficient of h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$125 = \frac{25 \pi}{\pi^{2/3}}h = 25\pi^{1/3}h \to h = \frac{5}{\pi^{1/3}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\pi \left(\frac{5}{\sqrt[3]{\pi}}\right)^2 = \frac{25 \pi}{\sqrt[3]{\pi}^2} = 25 \sqrt[3]{\pi}$$